# C++ bit7z : Exception thrown at ... in ... Microsoft C++ exception: bit7z::BitException at memory location 0x001AF440 & paths of directory and files

Tags: c++, qt, zip, visual-studio-2019, 7zip

I'm trying to create a program that, on execution, zips a given directory. Most of my errors have been resolved and I am hopefully getting to the end of this, but I still have the issue of an exception being thrown and a question regarding the program. I code in C++20 and on Visual Studio 2019.
I've come across this exact error when debugging the program:

```
Exception thrown at 0x76820B42 in aixLogger.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: bit7z::BitException at memory location 0x001AF440.
```

I already checked with a breakpoint what code is giving me this error:

```
catch (const BitException& ex) {
        ex.what(); //<-
    }
```

The code runs otherwise and isn't giving me any error messages, the breakpoint activates on the line I marked with an arrow (not actually part of my code).
To eliminate further possible edits I will add the rest of my code as well:

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <bit7z.hpp>
#include "main.h"
#include <bitcompressor.hpp>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace bit7z;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    try {
        Bit7zLibrary lib{ L"7z.dll" };
        BitCompressor compressor{ lib, BitFormat::Zip };

        //vector< wstring > files = { L"aretz/Downloads/test" };
        wstring dir = { L"D: / local / aretz / Programmierung / git - workplace / aixLogger / test /" } ;
        wstring zip = { L"zippedtest.zip" };

        compressor.compressDirectory(dir, zip);
    }
    catch (const BitException& ex) {
        ex.what();
    }

    return a.exec();
}

void AIXLogger::CompressDir() {
    /*try {
        Bit7zLibrary lib{ L"7z.dll" };
        BitCompressor compressor{ lib, BitFormat::Zip };

        vector< wstring > files = { L"C:/Users/aretz/Downloads/test" };
        wstring zip = { L"zippedtest.zip" };

        compressor.compressFiles(files, zip);
    }
    catch (const BitException& ex) {
        ex;
    }*/
}
```

main.h

```
#pragma once
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qobject.h>
#include <bit7z.hpp>

class AIXLogger : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:

public:
    void CompressDir();
};
```

I've currently commented out the function CompressDir() as I can't call it in my main since it gives me either a syntax error or tells me the identifier is undefined.
Syntax Error:
`AIXLogger.CompressDir(); the dot is marked as the error`
identifier is undefined:
`CompressDir();`

I don't know what exactly is causing the catch to thrown an exception. From other posts I suspected that my paths for the files and directories are at fault, but changing them or moving my test directory didn't help at all. Removing the try and catch lines from my codeblock only adds the same error message where Exception Thrown is being replaced by Unhandled Exception. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

> I already checked with a breakpoint what code is giving me this error:
>
> ```cpp
> catch (const BitException& ex) {
>         ex.what(); //<-
>     }
> ```
>
> The code runs otherwise and isn't giving me any error messages

The code isn't giving you any error message since you're not doing anything with the information provided by the thrown exception.
You're simply calling `ex.what()` without, for example, printing the error message string it returns, e.g., via `std::cout`.

> the breakpoint activates on the line I marked with an arrow (not actually
> part of my code).

> I don't know what exactly is causing the catch to thrown an exception. From other posts I suspected that my paths for the files and directories are at fault, but changing them or moving my test directory didn't help at all.

The `ex.what()` error message should give you more details about the actual issue you're having.

By the way, I'm the author of the bit7z library, and from my experience and looking at the code you posted, I can think of some possible causes (the most common ones):

- The program could not find the `7z.dll` library.

  - Please ensure that the DLL is in the same directory as the executable or in one of the default DLL search paths of Windows.
- The program could not find the directory path to be compressed.

  - As before, make sure that the path exists.